# Gaussian primes and an irrational number

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $p(n)$ be a Fibonacci number such that $p(n) = p(n-1) + p(n-2)$ for $p(1) = p(2) = 1$.
The golden ratio $(\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$ is diophantinely approximated:
as $n \to \infty$, $|p(n-1) \phi – p(n)| \to 0$.

Does the sequence $(p(n-1) + p(n) i)$ contain an infinite number of Gaussian primes?

Numerically it seems that the number of Gaussian primes divided by $n$ decreases to a number $ < 0.1$.

Comment: It would be more natural to look at $p_{n-1} \phi-p_n \in \mathbb{Z}[\phi]$ having some primes too.

Comment: So you are essential asking if $f_n^2 + f_{n-1}^2$ is prime. This is likely an open problem. Note that $8 + 5i$ is prime so the set is not empty. The choice of notation $p$ instead of $f$ seems a bit weird, is it a language thing?

Comment: @Aryabhata. $f_n^2+f_{n-1}^2=f_{2n-1}$ so the Q is whether there is a largest prime Fibonacci number. (...$ f_{2n}=f_ng_n$  where $(g_n)_n$ is the Lucas sequence, so $f_{2n}$ is composite for  $n\geq 3.$)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Ah! Great. Yes, so probably we can give a reference to the fact that this is still open.

Comment: @Aryabhata. The Wikipedia article Fibonacci Primes, which I just looked at.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Care to add an answer?

Comment: @Aryabhata, If I could! The Wikipedia article says the Q  is open and gives the largest known Fibonacci prime as of March 2017.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: "The question is still open. Here is a reference" is a perfectly valid answer!

Comment: Any particular reason to use $p$ rather than $F$?